# Python Pyqt QComboBox show options

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to create a GUI with button, text box and combo box. I have problems with the combo box. I can create it but once I click on it it does not display the options. I am not getting any error which makes me hard to find the problem. This is the code so far:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import  QtGui
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow,QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 5, 1100, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle("FourC Analyser")
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        self.app.setStyleSheet('QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(49,79,79);border: 1px solid black;}')


        extractAction = QtGui.QAction("&GET TO THE CHOPPAH!!!", self)
        extractAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        extractAction.setStatusTip('Leave The App')
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        labelCol1= 'color: rgb(255,250,205)'
        textboxCol1=("QLineEdit {background-color: rgb(49,79,79); color: rgb(218,165,32);}")

        #label
        self.lbl_project = QtGui.QLabel('Project Name', self)
        self.lbl_project.move(20, 120)
        self.lbl_project.setStyleSheet(labelCol1)

        #text box
        self.textbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 150)
        self.textbox.resize(280,30)
        self.textbox.setStyleSheet(textboxCol1)

        #Combo box
        self.cb=QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.cb = QComboBox()
        self.cb.addItems(["1","2","3"])


    def selectionchange(self,i):
        print "Items in the list are :"
        for count in range(self.cb.count()):
            print self.cb.itemText(count)
        print "Current index",i,"selection changed ",self.cb.currentText()

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
run()
```

Comment: You overwrite `self.cb` immediately after you first define it. Remove the latter row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining `self.cb` here:

```
self.cb = QComboBox()
```

By removing this line it works for me.
Both definitions work because of are your `import` statements. With `from PyQt4.QtGui import *` you import everythin within the module `QtGui` and with `from PyQt4 import  QtGui` you import the module `QtGui` itself. I recommend to remove `from PyQt4.QtGui import *`.